# Docker, Is it possible to form a cluster (swarm mode) with linux and mac?

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm-mode

> Per-container IP addressing is not possible The docker (Linux) bridge
>   network is not reachable from the macOS host

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

What does the above line mean? Does it mean you can't connect to docker on linux from docker on macOS ?

I did

```
docker swarm init // ubuntu
docker swarm join --token xx // mac

docker network inspect PL_default // can't see mac under peers section
```